# Git Authentication Failing for Private Repositories

Tags: git, authentication, github

I am trying to clone my git hub repositories on my desktop. I am able to clone any public repositories, but cloning my private repositories is giving me the below error

```
command:  
  git clone https://github.com/Anjul-Pathak/Test.git
error:
  remote: Repository not found.
  fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/Anjul-Pathak/Test.git/'

My Config file details are as follows:

git config --list

core.symlinks=true
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
rebase.autosquash=true
http.sslbackend=schannel
http.sslcainfo=/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
http.sslverify=false
http.proxy=https://UserId:Pwd@proxy.company.com:8080
https.sslverify=false
https.proxy=https://UserId:Pwd@proxy.company.com:8080
```

Same id pwd is working on Github Web interface. I have tried removing saved credentials from Windows Credential Manager but no luck. Please help

Comment: Try to set `credential.helper=wincred` in your config file. Perhaps also show `git config --list --show-origin`.

Answer (score 0):

You config list does not show your username. You can try setting up your user with `git config --global user.name "John Doe"` or `git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com`.